# How to copy a directory with its sub directories , files and zip files

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception, inputstream, fileinputstream

I am trying to copy directories (ex: My documents, Local Disk D) with all of its contents.The code I used is below.

```
 public void copyFolder(File inputLocation, File outputLocation) throws IOException
    {
       // FileUtils.copyDirectory(inputLocation, outputLocation);

        if (inputLocation.isDirectory())
        {

            //if directory not exists, create it
            if (!outputLocation.exists())
            {
                outputLocation.mkdir();
                System.out.println("Directory copied from "
                        + inputLocation + "  to " + outputLocation);
            }



            //list all the directory contents
            String files[] = inputLocation.list();

            for (String file : files)
            {
                //construct the src and dest file structure
                File srcFile = new File(inputLocation, file);
                File destFile = new File(outputLocation, file);
                //recursive copy
                copyFolder(srcFile, destFile);
            }

        } else
        {
            //if file, then copy it
            //Use bytes stream to support all file types
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputLocation);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputLocation);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes 
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("File copied from " + inputLocation + " to " + outputLocation);
        }
    }
```

This code fails as it generates an error. The error is simply happening because it "shifts" the path. The path I inserted to copy is "My Documents" and somehow it tried to copy "My Music" as well, which ended up in `nullPointerException` because the "My Music" is outside of "My Documents". It is also important to note that this is happening only for some input locations, not all the time.

The error I get is below.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx1.copyFolder(FolderCopy.java:52)
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx1.FolderCopy.copyFolder(FolderCopy.java:58)
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx1.ExpressWizard.noCompresionCheckBoxActionPerformed(ExpressWizard.java:2481)
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx1.ExpressWizard.access$4900(ExpressWizard.java:38)
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx1.ExpressWizard$30.actionPerformed(ExpressWizard.java:1413)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1654)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1606)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at com.theace.backupsystem.view.HomePanel.clickPanel01MouseClicked(HomePanel.java:653)
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx1.HomePanel.access$000(HomePanel.java:16)
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx1.HomePanel$1.mouseClicked(HomePanel.java:120)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6528)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4542)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The line 52 is

```
for (String file : files)
```

Please help me to fix my errors .

Comment: Which line is line 52?

Comment: @Jens: This is the Line `for (String file : files)`

Comment: Read the JavaDoc for File.list() method and modify your code to handle all possible values which can be returned from that method.

Comment: So it looks like ´inputLocation.list();` returns null. Add a null check before the loop

Comment: Why not use [`Files.copy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) instead in combination with [`Files.walkFileTree()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20int,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor)) instead?

Comment: Try to add some code like `System.out.println(file)` to see what do you have in the cycle.

Answer (score 2):

you could use these methods:

```
    Files.copy(source, target, options)
    Files.walkFileTree(Path start, Set<FileVisitOption> options, int maxDepth, FileVisitor<? super Path> visitor) throws IOException
```

Just walk thru the file tree, and in the FileVisitor do the copy.

example how to do that with working code:

change in this first example below one line, add the `<Path>` type to FileVisitor, like this:

```
        Files.walkFileTree(source, options, Integer.MAX_VALUE, new FileVisitor<Path>() {....
```

http://javatutorialhq.com/java/example-source-code/io/nio/folder-copy/

and this: http://www.studytrails.com/java-io/file-listing-directory-walking.jsp

Comment: Starting with Java 8 you also have `Files.walk()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not clear about the code and its parameters. Can you provide more detailed answer please?

Comment: By the way, the example in the blog will not work for cross filesystem copies

Comment: The given source is incorrect, because it the methods you have overriden do not exists.

Comment: There need to ba a change in this example, add the <Path> type to new FileVisitor(), should be: new FileVisitor<Path>();

Comment: @fge filesystem as defined by NIO.2 API. AFAIK you can copy data from one mounted partition to another mounted partition even if they have different native filesystems.

Comment: @Puce but you can't `.resolve()` a `Path` against another `Path` if both are from different `FileSystem`s (this throws a `ProviderMismatchException`). See also [here](http://fge.github.io/java7-fs-more/com/github/fge/filesystem/MorePaths.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path)).

Comment: @Puce also, what you are talking about is in fact `FileStore`s; this is how the different mounted partitions are represented in a multimount `FileSystem` under Unix. Under Windows you'd have one `FileStore` per "drive".

Comment: @fge I'm aware of that. I've written a similar library: http://www.softsmithy.org/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/PathUtils.html#resolve-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path- http://www.softsmithy.org/lib/current/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html I just wanted to make sure that the OP understands that when talking about "filesystems" in the NIO.2 File context, we don't mean native filesystems such as NTFS, ext4, FAT32 etc. but more like local disk, Zip files, ISO files, remote files etc.

Comment: @Puce interesting! Should we merge projects instead of reinventing the wheel over and over again? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apache `Commons IO` can do the trick for you. Have a look at [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

Example

```
File srcDir = new File("D:");
File destDir = new File("C:");
FileUtils.copyFolder(srcDir, destDir);
```

If you need to use java7 or +

```
public void copy(File source, File target) throws IOException {
    if (source.isDirectory())
        copyFolder(source, target);
    else
        copyFile(source, target);
}

private void copyFolder(File source, File target) throws IOException {
    if (!target.exists())
        target.mkdir();

    for (String f : source.list())
        copy(new File(source, f), new File(target, f));
}

private void copyFile(File source, File target) throws IOException {        
    try (
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target)
    ) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this already. The error is if it find a Zip, sometimes the program starts crashing.

Comment: You don't check for the results of mkdir(), which can fail

Answer (score 0):

(sorry for the self ad...)

If you use Java 7, you can have a go and try [one of my projects](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more); this allows you to do what you want:

```
final Path src = Paths.get(srcdir);
final Path dst = Paths.get(dstdir);

MoreFiles.copyRecursive(src, dst, RecursionMode.KEEP_GOING);
```

Note however that it will create the source in the destination; this may not be what you want. But then if you only want to copy the contents you can do that:

```
if (Files.isRegularFile(src))
    Files.copy(src, dst.resolve(src.getFileName().toString());
else {
    try (
        final Stream<Path> files = Files.list(src);
    ) {
        final List<Path> list = files.collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (final Path entry: list)
            MoreFiles.copyRecursive(entry, dst, RecursionMode.KEEP_GOING);
    }
}
```

Why I don't use the stream directly in the second example: it's because of the mess of handling checked exceptions in lambdas; but then again, and sorry for the self ad *again*, you may want to have a look at [throwing-lambdas](https://github.com/fge/throwing-lambdas) in this case, in which case copying directory entries can be done this way:

```
final Consumer<Path> copy 
    = Throwing.consumer(entry -> MoreFiles.copyRecursive(entry, dst, RecursionMode.KEEP_GOING);

try (
    final Stream<Path> files = Files.list(src);
) {
    files.forEach(copy);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not clear about this - `Note however that it will create the source in the destination`

Comment: Well, if `foo` is a directory, `MoreFiles.copyRecursive(foo, bar, ...)` will create `foo` in directory `bar`; this is what I mean

Comment: Good. That's what I want too. I will try.

Comment: By the way, [here's the javadoc for this method](http://fge.github.io/java7-fs-more/com/github/fge/filesystem/MoreFiles.html#copyRecursive(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20com.github.fge.filesystem.RecursionMode,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...))